XRDP connecting but not working properly
I just updated to Ubuntu 24.04 and having some weird problem with xrdp and remoting into my PC from my office laptop both have Ubuntu 24.04. Both the machines have xrdp enabled and I am using tailscale vpn.
Firstly remoting using Remmina works but shows a black screen (PC is logged out), as soon as I log in the pc, Remmina on the laptop starts working shows the login screen (need to logout of the PC to actually remote in and work) and everything is fine. Logout of remmina on the laptop try to connect again and it does not work again.
Older versions of ubuntu didnt had this issue, it was working as intended. Pretty new to Linux environments, so don't know what logs or config file to paste here. Please let me know if I need to paste some log or files and will edit the post.

I have been using ThinLinc remote desktop server software for one year, and it works well.
